# Using array list in Recycler view

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I'm new to recycler view.When I'm adding ArrayList to the custom adapter for RecycleView,it shows "indifferent formal and actual arguments"

My code for CustomAdapter is..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] mDataset;

ArrayList<HashMap<String ,String>> productList;
Context myContext;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView dispname;
    public TextView dispphno;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        dispname=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispname);
        dispphno=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispphno);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MenuAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> productList) {

    this.productList=productList;
    //this.myContext=myContext;
}


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MenuAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                 int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.menu_card, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout paramete
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    //holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    HashMap<String,String> map=productList.get(position);
    holder.dispname.setText(map.get("name"));
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
}
```

The problem is here..

```
adapter=new MenuAdapter(productsList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I initialised the adapter as,

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

I get this

[image: Error while ruuning]

Comment: `productsList` must be in this format: `ArrayList<HashMap<String ,String>>`

Answer (score 0):

`productsList` your passing in construcotr must be in this format: `ArrayList<HashMap<String ,String>>`

And set the `ArrayList` length in `getItemCount()` like this

```
// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productsList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes i found. First use like this

```
MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(Myclass.this, productsList)
```

then

```
public MenuAdapter(Context myContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> productList) {  
    this.productList=productList;
    this.myContext=myContext;
}
```

then

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
  return productsList.size();
}
```

Change this line here. Issue is in inflating the layout

```
@Override
public MenuAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                             int viewType) {
 // create a new view
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(myContext)
        .inflate(R.layout.menu_card, parent, false);
 // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout paramete
 ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
 return vh;
}
```

Comment: Pls check again, I've updated the answer. In onCreateView simply change the line View v = LayoutInflater.from(context, R.layour.menu_card, parent, false)

Comment: did yu got your ans or not ? @Noormuhammed

Comment: I've found the error.The problem is with the name I used for Adapter class. The code runs fine when I changed that!

Answer (score 0):

> Change **mDataset.length -> productList.size() in getItemCount()**.

```
// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you pass the Data in mDataset array. Replace with productsList.size().

Replace code with:

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
//return mDataset.length
  return productsList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error.
The error is with the name of the class, MenuAdapter. MenuAdapter is a inbuilt class. So I changed the name and now it runs. :)
Thanks all for your suggestions..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the same array list to the adapter constructor, please double check if you passed it correctly.